# Dynamic assignement of arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

In my project, in one of the classes (Adventure) I created an ArrayList and worked on it (add elements, delete others...)

This ArrayList is then passed as a parameter when creating an instance of another class (Player) inside Adventure.

Therefore I of course needed to created an ArrayList in Player and constructor, to catch the ArrayList sent from Adventure.

I'm not really sure, that all what i've done is correct. I'm getting the warning in Player Class:

> This private field "createdObjects" is never assigned

Should i change smtg, or just ignore the warning ?

Here's the code :

```
public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Objects> createdObjects;

    public Player(ArrayList<Objects> createdObjects) {
       //Originally i have many other elements in this constructor
       // but i let only what concerns this arrayList
    }
 
    public ArrayList<Objects> getCreatedObjects() {
        return createdObjects;
    }
}
```

```
public class Adventure {

    private ArrayList<Objects> createdObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Objects> getCreatedObjects() {
        return createdObjects;
    }

    // ...methods that will add/modify... the arraylist

        public Player letsStart(){
            Player player = new Player(createdObjects);
            return player;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*Should i change smtg*". Yes. Assign the field.

Comment: As in `this.createdObjects = createdObjects`inside your constructor. You'll need to tell your program that it should save/assign the passed list to the field you created. There is no automatic magic that does this assigning for you, no matter if both fields have the same name and type

Comment: The warning is made by what @OHGODSPIDERS said but also consider to not use `Object` as a generic type for your list. Always use static types, in your case I don't know of what type could be that `ArrayList` because you're missing in details. Use `List` instead of `ArrayList` too.

Comment: @Virgula It is actually `Objects` not `Object` (note the extra **s** at the end). Which of course is also not very good style to create a custom class with such a name..

Comment: I didn’t even notice that it’s Objects which is totally wrong. Objects is a class which contains utilities and static methods it is completely different from Object and it’s of course, wrong. Use Object instead of Objects isn’t a good choice anyway .

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS  but isn't the assignment automatic when i created the instance of Player and passed the arraylist as a parameter ? Meaning that whenever i create an instance of player from "Adventure" then this instance of player will have access to the elements in the ArrayList createdObjects ??

Comment: @Virgula i'll change it, thanks !

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS note that all instances of Player will be created through the method letsStart() in "Adventure" and never manually in another class...